# Quantitative bound on irrational rotation recurrence time

Tags: real-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Given an irrational $a$, the sequence $b_n := na$ is dense and equidistributed in $\mathbb S^1$ where we view $\mathbb S^1$ as  $[0, 1]$ with its endpoints identified.

Given a point $p$ in $\mathbb S^1$, can we obtain a quantitative upper bound (that can depend on $a, p, e$) on the smallest $n$ such that $na$ is in $B_e (p)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably suboptimal, but one can use the convergents of the continued fraction expansion of $a$ to efficiently find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $||na||_\mathbb{Z} \leq e$, where $||\cdot||_\mathbb{Z}$ denotes the distance to the nearest integer. Then one can find $m \in \mathbb{N}$ with $m \leq ||na||_\mathbb{Z}^{-1}$ such that $|mna-p| \leq e$.

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thanks!

Comment: Btw, could you elaborate just a little more on the construction itself?

Comment: Let $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ be the convergents of the continued fraction of $a$, defined as in the Wikipedia article on continued fractions. One has $|a - \frac{p_n}{q_n}| \leq \frac{1}{q_n^2}$ so that $|q_na-p_n| \leq \frac{1}{q_n}$ and therefore $||q_na||_{\mathbb{Z}} \leq \frac{1}{q_n}$.

Comment: One also has $\frac{1}{q_{n+1}+q_n} \leq |q_na - p_n|$ so this gives an upper bound on $m$.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the answer from @burtonpeterj is in fact pretty much best possible. Note that it does not utilize $p.$ I don't think there is a way to work general values of $p$ into the estimate.

If you take the fractional parts of $0,a,2a,3a,\cdots,na$ they divide $[0,1]$ into sub-intervals. The [three gap theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-gap_theorem) states that there will be at most three distinct lengths. The particular lengths can be determined from the convergents mentioned above.

This allows us to find the smallest $n$ so that all the sub-intervals have length $2e$ or less. Then this would work for all values of $p$ in the unit interval and be the right one for  $p$ being the middle of the last interval of longer length which get split (and any points close enough to it.)

Here are a few special cases which illustrate what can happen.

- If $a=\alpha$ is positive but much smaller than $e$ ($\alpha \ll e)$ then at about $n=\frac{1-2e}{\alpha}$ we have lots of intervals of length $a$ and one just barely under $2e.$
- The case that $a=\frac{p}{q}$ is rational doesn't really fit the question but, ignoring that, we see that at $n=q-1$ there is an interval of length $\frac2{q}$ which gets split exactly in half. Then we just get the points we had before.
- If $a=\frac{p}{q}+\alpha$ is irrational with $|\alpha| \ll e \ll \frac1q $ then up to about $n=q$ it is just about like for $a=\frac{p}{q}$ and at that point we have $q$ subintervals all of length about $\frac1q.$  Then the following fractional parts start chipping off new subintervals of length $|\alpha|.$